# Setting checkbox "checked" attribute according to "value"

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a checkbox field in a `.cshtml` form with next attributes:

```
@Html.CheckBox("InFooter", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "edit_rssFeed_InFooter" })
```

Now, using ajax I am setting value to "value" attribute of this checkbox:

```
$('#edit_rssFeed_InFooter').val(rss.InFooter);
```

where `InFooter` is boolean value (true or false). So, with this line, I get `value=true/false` attribute generated.

I would like to set attribute `checked="checked"` when attribute `value=true`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use as

```
  $('#edit_rssFeed_InFooter').prop("checked",rss.InFooter);
```

Comment: Wow! I listed the same answer *1 second* before you... Never been that close before :)

Answer (score 1):

Always use `prop('checked', value)` when dealing with check boxes (not `val()`).

See if this does the trick:

```
$('#edit_rssFeed_InFooter').prop('checked', rss.InFooter);
```